# How to get location of all user without hitting github API usage limit

Tags: python, github, github-api, github3.py

Currently I am trying to get all Github user location. I am using github3 python library to get the location. But it gives me over-API usage error when my api calls are more than 5K. Here is my code.

```
import github3
from datetime import datetime
import sys

def main(pswd):
    g = github3.login(username="rakeshcusat", password=pswd)
    current_time = datetime.now()   
    fhandler = open("githubuser_"+current_time.strftime("%d-%m-%y-%H:%M:%S"), "w")

    for user in g.iter_all_users():
        user.refresh()
        try:
            fhandler.write(" user: {0}, email: {1}, location: {2}\n".format(str(user), str(user.email), str(user.location)))
        except:
            print "Something wrong, user id : {0}".format(user.id);


    fhandler.close()        

if __name__ == "__main__":

    if len(sys.argv) == 2:

        main(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        print "Please provide your password"
```

I can do this by downloading all username first which will be only single API call. And then iteratively download the user location. If hit over-usage then wait for one hour and resume the api call where it was left. But this seems like a lame solution and definitely it will take more time(almost 25+ hours). Can some one provide me better way of doing this?

Comment: @sigmavirus24 Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Sorry it didn't ping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you use the development version of github3.py you can use the per_page parameter, e.g.,

```
for user in g.iter_all_users(per_page=200):
    user.refresh()
    #: other logic
```

The thing is, you'll save 7 requests using `per_page` (1 request now returns 25 if I remember correctly, so you'll get the equivalent of 8 requests in 1). The problem is you're then using 200 requests rather quickly with `User#refresh`. What you could do, to avoid the ratelimit is to use sleep in your code to space out your requests. 5000 requests split over 3600 seconds is 1.389 requests per second. If each request takes half a second (which I think is an underestimation personally), you could do

```
import time

for user in g.iter_all_users(per_page=200):
    user.refresh()
    #: other logic
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

This will make sure one request is made per second and that you never hit the ratelimit. Regardless, it's rather lame.

In the future, I would store these values in the database using the user's id as the id in the database and then just look for the max and try to start there. I'll have to check if `/users` supports something akin to the `since` parameter. Alternatively, you could also work like so

```
import time

i = g.iter_all_users(per_page=200):
for user in i:
    user.refresh()
    #: other logic
    time.sleep(0.5)

# We have all users
# store i.etag somewhere then later
i = g.iter_all_users(per_page=200, etag=i.etag)
for user in i:
    user.refresh()
    #: etc
```

The second iterator should give you all new users since the last one in your last request if I remember correctly but I'm currently very tired so I could be remembering something wrong.

Comment: For users API from github API documentation "Note: Pagination is powered exclusively by the 'since' parameter. Use the Link header to get the URL for the next page of users." This means user does support since parameter. @sigmavirus24 can you give me any example how to use since parameter in iter_all_users() api call?

Comment: @Rakesh I just realized I never answered you. If you keep the id of the last user you'll be able to pass `since=id` in a new version of github3.py. I apparently never added that parameter to `iter_all_users`.